# Sending HTML EMail uing WPF Desktop Application

Tags: c#, wpf, html-email

I am looking to build an Email Desktop Application for Bulk Email Sending with Html Templates.
I Used the basics of system.net.mail and successfully sent a plain text  mail .But now I want to  add a HTML content to mail which Suitable for BULK Mail.

Please provide me the links which explain my needs or show the code with an example

Comment: And should we be enthusiastic about helping someone to send bulk mail?

Comment: @Henk I do this quite often, too. E.g. several Intranet application we wrote for big customers notify users on a daily basis that they have new items to process in their workflow queue inside these Intranet applications. I would call that "bulk", too. So from my point-of-view, the term "bulk" has no negative association at all.

Comment: @Henk Holterman , Why  you think so ?

Comment: @Sathyam He assumes "bulk" == "spam", I guess.

Comment: @Uwe: I know it can be legitimate. But the OP should realize this is not a neutral topic.

Comment: @HENK , dude if you are  ethical , just ignore this question

Comment: Sathyam, does that mean your intentions here are not ethical?

Comment: no not like that , i mean , BULK Mail is not a Spam , its great tool to save our time from sending thousands of mail Manually to our customers who requires information from us. I need this to  better my service to our customers . So , in my view its Ethical .

Answer (score 2):

Using System.Net.Mail, this is trivially easy - just set `MailMessage.IsBodyHtml` to true, then fill in the body with a string of HTML.  See MSDN : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.isbodyhtml.aspx

Of course, generating pretty HTML is the harder part, but there's lots of ways to do that.

Comment: Thank You ,  your referred link is very useful.